Python connection timeouts to a Redis cluster
As per title,
I am struggling to make a connection with a Redis cluster using the redis.asyncio library (it works perfectly fine with master/slave configuration). I created a simple test to check the connection and it timeouts. Surely I got something wrong here:
import asyncio
from redis.asyncio.cluster import RedisCluster

async def test_redis_connection():
    try:
        # Connect to the Redis cluster
        redis = RedisCluster.from_url('redis://localhost:6379', encoding='utf-8', decode_responses=True)

        # Test the connection by setting and getting a value
        await redis.set('key1', 'bar')
        value = await redis.get('key1')

        # Print the result
        print(f"Connection successful, value: {value}")

        # Close the connection
        await redis.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Connection failed: {e}")

asyncio.run(test_redis_connection())

For completeness, the redis cluster lives in my k8s cluster, the cluster is deployed using the bitnami redis-cluster chart, and I am port-forwarding the created service.
The above is successfully tested using the redis-cli utility. It can find the other 6 members of the cluster without issues.

Silly, mistake found with the redis-cli -c command. The node pool is not reachable unless you portforward all of them. Everything works within a pod in k8s environment.
